# Visual Studio Fonts and Colors Settings

Tags: visual-studio

## Duplicate:

> [What color scheme do you use for programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951/what-color-scheme-do-you-use-for-programming)
>
> [Visual Studio color theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841/visual-studio-color-theme)
>
> [Visual Studio color settings for better eye](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99792/visual-studio-color-settings-for-better-eye)

I'm using Visual Studio IDE. I tried to use some different visual settings but no one is satisfied. Can someone recommend some good settings for healthy eyes?

Comment: Duplicate of at least two questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99792/visual-studio-color-settings-for-better-eye http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841/visual-studio-color-theme http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951/what-color-scheme-do-you-use-for-programming

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ported a version of VIM's inkpot color scheme to a .vssettings file a while back.  It's a nice dark style that is very easy on my eyes.

[image: InkPot]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/jaredpar/WindowsLiveWriter/InkpotColorScheme_12121/Inkpot_2.png))</sub>

The .vssettings file for the scheme is available here: http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2008/06/02/inkpot-color-scheme.aspx